# windows processes xml file to pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, xml, pandas, dataframe

i would like to convert the results of the following windows command to a pandas dataframe.

raw data is generated with this command on windows machine

> wmic process get Caption, Processid, ParentProcessId, CommandLine,
>   CreationDate, KernelModeTime, UserModeTime, ThreadCount, HandleCount,
>   WorkingSetSize, PeakWorkingSetSize, VirtualSize, PeakVirtualSize,
>   PageFaults, PageFileUsage, PeakPageFileUsage, ReadOperationCount,
>   WriteOperationCount, OtherOperationCount /format:rawxml

with the following code

```
with f.open("RunningProcess.xml") as praw:

etree = et.parse(praw)
xroot = etree.getroot()
nprop = []

for property in xroot.iter("PROPERTY"):
    xnames = property.get("NAME")
    nprop.append(xnames)

npropf = pandas.DataFrame(index=nprop)
rprows = []
data = []
inner = {}

for child in xroot.iter("PROPERTY"):
    for gchild in child.iterfind('VALUE'):
        inner[gchild.tag] = gchild.text
    data.append(inner)
    rprows.append(pandas.DataFrame(data))
    data = []; inner = {}

finaldf = pandas.concat(rprows, sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)


finaldf.index = nprop


rpdfhtml = finaldf.to_html(index=True, header=True, border=1)
```

I get this result

[first 39 lines of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sz3D1.png)

I would like to

- make the first 20 index rows to columns (caption to
  WriteOperationCount)
- make values column as rows instead.

like this example 
[first 9 columns of desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sbDM.png)

Comment: Hello! Do you have a copy of the XML you're looking to parse?

Comment: hey! I managed to get what I think is the data you're working with.. i've provide an answer below which **might** help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome! This was an interesting question. This isn't perfect but hopefully it helps

I wanted to try to avoid hard coding any columns of interest.

**Assumptions** - This file will have a predictable pattern of field names.

I used `xml.etree.ElementTree`, I find this to a straight forward library

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
```

reference the xml file

```
file = '/location/to/file/RunningProcess.xml'
```

Create flattened DataFrame. I personally find this easier to parse than working entirely within the xml pulling the XML

First create a flatted list

```
tree = ET.parse(file)
root = tree.getroot()

ls_processes = []

for COMMAND in root.iter('COMMAND'):
    for RESULTS in COMMAND.iter('RESULTS'):
        for PROPERTY in RESULTS.iter('PROPERTY'):

            VALUE = PROPERTY.find('VALUE') 

            if VALUE is not None:
                print(PROPERTY.attrib['NAME'],'|',PROPERTY.attrib['TYPE'],'|', VALUE.text )
                ls_processes.append([PROPERTY.attrib['NAME'],PROPERTY.attrib['TYPE'], VALUE.text])
            else:
                print(PROPERTY.attrib['NAME'],'|',PROPERTY.attrib['TYPE'],'|', "NO VALUE")
                ls_processes.append([PROPERTY.attrib['NAME'],PROPERTY.attrib['TYPE'], 'NO VALUE'])
```

This will produce something which looks a bit like this

```
Caption | string | System Idle Process
CommandLine | string | NO VALUE
CreationDate | datetime | 20191002111400.978894+060
HandleCount | uint32 | 0
KernelModeTime | uint64 | 159488690156250
OtherOperationCount | uint64 | 0
```

Transform into a Dataframe

```
df_processes = pd.DataFrame(ls_processes)
```

Rename columns to make the Dataframe easier to work with

```
df_processes.columns = ['data','type','value']
```

Create a list of columns of interest

```
ls_columns = ['Caption', 'ProcessId', 'ParentProcessId', 'CommandLine', 'CreationDate', 'KernelModeTime', 'UserModeTime', 'ThreadCount', 'HandleCount', 'WorkingSetSize', 'PeakWorkingSetSize', 'VirtualSize', 'PeakVirtualSize', 'PageFaults', 'PageFileUsage', 'PeakPageFileUsage', 'ReadOperationCount', 'WriteOperationCount', 'OtherOperationCount']
```

Create Dataframe columns of each column of interest

```
ls_processes = []
for column in ls_columns:
    print(column)
    ls_row = []
    for index, row in df_processes.iterrows():
        if row['data'] == column: 
            ls_row.append(row['value'])

    df = pd.DataFrame(ls_row)
    ls_processes.append(df)
```

Concat the Dataframes together by columns

```
df_processes_flat = pd.concat(ls_processes, axis = 1 )
```

Add the column names using the list previously created

```
df_processes_flat.columns = ls_columns
```

You'll end up with a Dataframe which looks like this

[image]

I would say these steps aren't possible the most *elegant* but hopefully it's clear whats going on.

Comment: exactly what i was looking for , many thanks for taking your time to provide this solution!