# Web scraping problem during passing fuction as paramater in function

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hello I've created two functions  that work well well called alone. But when I try to use a for loop with these functions I got a problem with my parameter.

First function to search and get link to pass to the second one.

```
USER_AGENT = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'}

def searchsport(terme):
        url = 'https://www.verif.com/recherche/{}/1/ca/d/?ville=null'.format(terme)
        response = requests.get(url, headers= USER_AGENT)
        response.raise_for_status()
        return terme, response.text
    
def crawl(keyword):    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        try:
            keyword, html = searchsport(keyword)
            soup = bs(html,'html.parser')
            table = soup.find_all('td', attrs={'class': 'verif_col1'})

            premier = []
            for result in table:
                link = result.find('a', href=True)
                premier.append(link)
                truelink = 'https://www.verif.com/'+str(premier[0]).split('"')[1]
            #print("le lien", truelink)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        finally:
            time.sleep(10)
    return truelink
```

Second function to **scrape** a link.

```
def single_text(item_url):
    source_code = requests.get(item_url)
    print('nivo1 ok')
    plain_text = source_code.text # La page en html avec toutes ces balises
    soup = bs(plain_text,features="lxml" ) 
    print('nivo2 ok')
    table = soup.find('table',{'class':"table infoGen hidden-smallDevice"}) # on cherche que la balise table
    print('nivo1 ok', '\n', table)
    table_rows = table.find_all('tr') # les données de tables sont dans les celulles tr
    #print(table_rows)

    l = []
    for tr in table_rows:
        td = tr.find_all('td')
        row = row = [tr.text.strip() for tr in td] 
        l.append(row)
        # On enleve certains caractères unitiles
        df = pd.DataFrame(l)
    return df
```

All these function worked when I tested them on a link.

Now I have a csv file with name of companies using searchsport()  to search in website and the returned link is passed to single_text() to scrape.

```
for keyword in list(pd.read_csv('sport.csv').name):
    l = crawl(keyword)
    print(l) # THIS PRINT THE LINK
    single_item(l)    # HERE I GOT THE PROBLEME
```

Error:

```
nivo1 ok
nivo2 ok
nivo1 ok 
 None

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-263d95d6748c> in <module>
      3     l = crawl(keyword)
      4 
----> 5     single_item(item_url=l)

<ipython-input-53-6d3b5c1b1ee8> in single_item(item_url)
      7     table = soup.find('table',{'class':"table infoGen hidden-smallDevice"}) # on cherche que la balise table
      8     print('nivo1 ok', '\n', table)
----> 9     table_rows = table.find_all('tr') # les données de tables sont dans les celulles tr
     10     #print(table_rows)
     11 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

When I run this I got a df.

```
single_item(item_url="https://www.verif.com/societe/COMPANYNAME-XXXXXXXXX/").head(1)
```

My expected results should be two DataFrame for every keyword.
Why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have noted throughout the code some of the problems I saw with your code as posted.

Some things I noticed:

Not handling cases of where something is not found e.g. 'PARIS-SAINT-GERMAIN-FOOTBALL' will fail whereas 'PARIS SAINT GERMAIN FOOTBALL' as a search term will not

Opportunities for simplification missed e.g. creating a dataframe by looping `tr` then `td` when could just use `read_html` on `table`; Using find_all when a single `table` or `a` tag is needed

Overwriting variables in loops as well as typos e.g.

```
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = row = [tr.text.strip() for tr in td]  # presumable a typo with row = row
```

Not testing if a dataframe is empty

Risking generating incorrect urls by using `'https://www.verif.com/'` as the next part you concatenate on starts with "/" as well

Inconsistent variable naming e.g. what is `single_item`? The function I see is called `single_text`.

These are just some observations and there is certainly still room for improvement.

```
import requests, time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd


def searchsport(terme):
    url = f'https://www.verif.com/recherche/{terme}/1/ca/d/?ville=null'
    response = requests.get(url, headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
    response.raise_for_status()
    return terme, response.text


def crawl(keyword):      
    try:
        keyword, html = searchsport(keyword)
        soup = bs(html,'lxml')
        a_tag = soup.select_one('td.verif_col1 a[href]') 
        # your code before when looping tds would just overwrite truelink if more than one found. Instead
        if a_tag is None:
             #handle case of no result e.g. with using crawl('PARIS-SAINT-GERMAIN-FOOTBALL') instead of
             #crawl('PARIS SAINT GERMAIN FOOTBALL')
            truelink = ''
        else:
            # print(a_tag['href'])
            # adding to the list premier served no purpose. Using split on href would result in list index out of range
            truelink = f'https://www.verif.com{a_tag["href"]}'  #relative link already so no extra / after .com

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        truelink = '' #handle case of 'other' fail. Make sure there is an assigment
    finally:
        time.sleep(5)
    return truelink #unless try succeeded this would have failed with local variable referenced before assignment


def single_text(item_url):
    source_code = requests.get(item_url, headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
    print('nivo1 ok')
    plain_text = source_code.text # La page en html avec toutes ces balises
    soup = bs(plain_text,features="lxml") 
    print('nivo2 ok')
    table = soup.select_one('.table') # on cherche que la balise table
    #print('nivo1 ok', '\n', table)
    if table is None:
        df = pd.DataFrame()
    else:
        df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0] #simplify to work direct with table and pandas;avoid your loops
    return df

def main():

    terms = ['PARIS-SAINT-GERMAIN-FOOTBALL', 'PARIS SAINT GERMAIN FOOTBALL']

    for term in terms:
        item_url = crawl(term)
        if item_url:
            print(item_url)
            df = single_text(item_url)  # what is single_item in your question? There is single_text
            if not df.empty: #test if dataframe is empty
                print(df.head(1)) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

Returning df from main()

```
import requests, time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd


def searchsport(terme):
    url = f'https://www.verif.com/recherche/{terme}/1/ca/d/?ville=null'
    response = requests.get(url, headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
    response.raise_for_status()
    return terme, response.text


def crawl(keyword):      
    try:
        keyword, html = searchsport(keyword)
        soup = bs(html,'lxml')
        a_tag = soup.select_one('td.verif_col1 a[href]') 
        # your code before when looping tds would just overwrite truelink if more than one found. Instead
        if a_tag is None:
             #handle case of no result e.g. with using crawl('PARIS-SAINT-GERMAIN-FOOTBALL') instead of
             #crawl('PARIS SAINT GERMAIN FOOTBALL')
            truelink = ''
        else:
            # print(a_tag['href'])
            # adding to the list premier served no purpose. Using split on href would result in list index out of range
            truelink = f'https://www.verif.com{a_tag["href"]}'  #relative link already so no extra / after .com

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        truelink = '' #handle case of 'other' fail. Make sure there is an assigment
    finally:
        time.sleep(5)
    return truelink #unless try succeeded this would have failed with local variable referenced before assignment


def single_text(item_url):
    source_code = requests.get(item_url, headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
    print('nivo1 ok')
    plain_text = source_code.text # La page en html avec toutes ces balises
    soup = bs(plain_text,features="lxml") 
    print('nivo2 ok')
    table = soup.select_one('.table') # on cherche que la balise table
    #print('nivo1 ok', '\n', table)
    if table is None:
        df = pd.DataFrame()
    else:
        df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0] #simplify to work direct with table and pandas;avoid your loops
    return df

def main():

    terms = ['PARIS-SAINT-GERMAIN-FOOTBALL', 'PARIS SAINT GERMAIN FOOTBALL']

    for term in terms:
        item_url = crawl(term)
        if item_url:
            #print(item_url)
            df = single_text(item_url)  # what is single_item in your question? There is single_text

    return df

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = main()
    print(df)
```

Comment: singte_text is equivalent to single item I miss name here

Comment: I've got this output ```name 's' is not defined```

Comment: Yes that's i did

Comment: I can not access pastebin du to proxy i think. 

    Access Denied (policy_denied)

Comment: one last question the df is into function, how to get it out so when I call it I'll get the data?

Comment: if not df.empty: print(df)    ?

Comment: if not df.empty: print(df)    ?

Comment: i mean when I need df out of the function.

Comment: what are you going to do with it? It is there in Main() ready to be used. You could have it then returned from Main (turning Main into a function)

Comment: I'd like to save it to csv file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201075/discussion-between-qharr-and-abdoulsn).

Answer (score 1):

Your error suggests that you trying to run find_all() against a variable which hasn't been populated, i.e. a tag wasn't found to which you could run find_all() against. I have dealt with this by including a statement testing for **NoneType**

```
if VALUE is not None:
    ## code when the tag is found
else:
    ## code when tag is not found
```

I think this is the bit you need to do an update like this,

```
  for tr in table_rows:
    if tr is not None:
        td = tr.find_all('td')
        row = row = [tr.text.strip() for tr in td] 
        l.append(row)
        # On enleve certains caractères unitiles
        df = pd.DataFrame(l)
    else:
        ## code to run when tr isn't populated
```

There's a more colourful example where some XML is being parsed where this in action [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58380253/windows-processes-xml-file-to-pandas-dataframe/58384857#58384857)

Comment: Why if I test it alone it works with the same url? I mean when I run single_text() in findall the tr is not None, it’s None only when it’s in for loop. I thought it was a type problem. But it isn’t as I wrapped l in str. But it still don’t work.

Comment: I think its failing at the point here **table_rows = table.find_all('tr')** in single_text(), the page associated to that URL provided doesn't have a table. Are you saying that you tested exactly the same URL outside of a loop and found that section works when running single_text()?

Comment: Yes that’s. For example this   This keyword PARIS-SAINT-GERMAIN-FOOTBALL in searchsport() will return a link and this link https://www.verif.com/societe/PARIS-SAINT-GERMAIN-FOOTBALL-382357721/  in single_text() will return df.

Comment: When I run just single_text(item_url="http://verif.com/societe/PARIS-SAINT-GERMAIN-FOOTBALL-382357721").head(1) this fails for me with the same error you show above.  From what I can see, this **table = soup.find('table',{'class':"table infoGen hidden-smallDevice"}) ** doesn't find anything so when this is attempted **table_rows = table.find_all('tr') **  table variable is actually **None** so the find_all('tr') can't run

Comment: single_text problem I thing, I miss named it